# Acute 404 errors from Pelican blog on localhost

Tags: pelican

After a few generations of my pelican site, suddenly after changing the theme once my localhost has tries to find all files non-relatively. 
`WARNING:root:Unable to find file /jonocodes.com/theme/css/main.css/index.html or variations.`
I believe it should be looking for my file in `/localhost/theme/css/main.css/index.html`.

Where is this getting generated? I have not edited my publishconf.py and my page template is the default.

Is there any good reason why it suddenly started messing up after working for a while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue I was having, and I still can't explain why it happened all of a sudden, was that I had added the field `'SITEURL'` to my pyconfig. This made everything relative to the SITEURL and so it did this on local host and of course didn't work.